# CKEDITOR is not defined when I get returned data from my AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor5

I'm using CKeditor5's Inline Editor Build.

I have used AJAX to post form fields and received the data from my backend, which I want to add to the field.

In my html head, I have the CKEditor5 Inline editor CDN, followed by bootstrap, then link to style.css.
Before my body tag, I have Jquery CDN, followed by link to script.js

**editor.php**

```
<p class='description box' id="description"> {add text from database} </p>
```

My javascript file and specific ajax call:

```
$("#selection").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the values of the form
    var chosenType = $(".reportType").val();
    var chosenTrait = $(".trait").val();
    var chosenAssess = $(".assessment").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "show.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {chosenType: chosenType, chosenTrait: chosenTrait, chosenAssess: chosenAssess},
        success: function (data) {

            // fill in description
            var trait_description = data.trait_description;
            CKEDITOR.instances['description'].setData(trait_description);
        }
    })
});
```

However I get this in my console:
script.js:82 Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Comment: Have you added script files for CKEDITOR? If yes, change position of CKEDITOR script url before your script.js in `<head>`

Comment: It's not `CKEDITOR` for version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how you can interact with the editor (for CKEditor 5) was described in the [basic API](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html) article.

The instance of the editor is not anymore available through the `CKEDITOR` global. That global doesn't exist at all.

You can get the instance of the editor only through the promise returned from the `create()` method, like here:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#description' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

Then, you can store it in your app. For the purpose of this example, I'll use a global variable:

```
let appEditor;

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#description' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        // Store it in more "global" context.
        appEditor = editor;
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );

$("#selection").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the values of the form
    var chosenType = $(".reportType").val();
    var chosenTrait = $(".trait").val();
    var chosenAssess = $(".assessment").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "show.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {chosenType: chosenType, chosenTrait: chosenTrait, chosenAssess: chosenAssess},
        success: function (data) {

            // fill in description
            var trait_description = data.trait_description;
            appEditor.setData( trait_description );
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it had something to do with the promise result but putting it in the global really solved it :)